# Running an aliased command in csh and storing it in a variable

Tags: csh

In my csh script, I'd like to run a command that has been aliased. For example,

```
#hello_world.pl is aliased as hw
set temp = `hw`
echo $temp
```

However, I get the error `echo: No match.`. I've seen posts saying that the backticks work, but they were for Linux commands (i.e. `ls`). Is it possible to do it via an alias, or do I have to do something like

```
set temp = `/path/to/hello_world.pl`
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Needs to have quotations around `$temp`:

`echo "$temp"`